# Collision/Trigger detection between two remote objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to have a script in a GameEngine script and have it check for collisions between two remote objects that are not connected to the GameEngine script, via `Update()` or `OnTriggerStay()`/`OnColliderStay()`?

My plan for this script is to detect situations such as putting out room that is on fire. My original plan was to have a collider around this room checking for fire particles, and if there are no more particles, the fire is out. If you have a better suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring with linear motion. If so Ray Casting is the solution. Ray Casting is forming a line or vector from a specific point to another point in a 3D plane. The purpose of the ray (vector) is to determine if it intersects with any colliders or other game objects.

It can be simply used like,

```
void Update() {
    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    // parameters are origin, direction and length of the ray. 
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10)){ 
        print("There is something in front of the object!");
    }

}
```

You can find more references and tutorials on the internet. Try Unity official tutorial on [Raycasting](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/raycasting)

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear, I updated the question. Originally I planned to have this collider check for fire particles in a room, and have a boolean status if there is a fire or not.

Comment: I can give you a suggestion, If I did it I would use a static variable of on a class like, `static bool hasFire;` and set it `true/false` based on the requirement! light weight and flexible!
If you're not happy with it I will think of another way!

Comment: The flag is not my issue, the issue is checking if there's fire in the room or not.

Comment: who is setting the fire?

Comment: you could try an Observer design pattern, with the fire registering with the room when it set it alight and deregistering when they are put out. This way each room knows what fire's it contains without having to "detect" them.

Comment: Yeah that would be the most preferable way!

Comment: At the moment, fire is a "dumb" entity, where it just exists and spreads, with no knowledge if its alive or not. The fire exists when the level starts, and it spreads on its own. I'll try your idea if mine doesn't work out because the fire class is not mine.